# How do Async coroutineBuilders execute tasks written in it concurrently in the same Main Thread when there are executing in parallell

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**My code:**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis
fun main() {
    runBlocking{
        val time = measureTimeMillis{
            val m1 = async{
                delay(2000)
                println("First async :" + Thread.currentThread().name)
                "Hello"
            }
            val m2 = async{
                delay(2000)
                println("Second async :" + Thread.currentThread().name)
                " World"
            }
            val j = m1.await()+m2.await()
            println(j)
        }
        println("Time is : "+time.toString())
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
First async :main @coroutine#2
Second async :main @coroutine#3
Hello World
Time is : 2029
```

But how is this executing in 2 seconds and running on the same main thread instead of running on an other thread?

Can anybody explain me in detail how these coroutines here work, please?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html https://doordash.engineering/2021/11/09/the-beginners-guide-to-kotlin-coroutine-internals/amp/ https://kt.academy/article/cc-under-the-hood

Comment: This is pretty much what coroutines are and do. They allow threads to jump from one execution context to another and back. Just to be strict: these code blocks don't execute in parallel, but they execute concurrently.